# Is there a trick to get multi-line labels in gephi?

Tags: gephi

I worked with "record" labels in GraphViz so far but now I want to use gephi because my graphs become really big.

I have labels with 3 to 5 lines and several data elements that should be shown.

Unfortunately the default of gephi is to separate attribute values by "-" and print them side-by-side.

Is there a way to convince gephi to break the label string at certain indicated positions or (as a hack) to separate attribute values not by "-" but by centering all attribute values and printing them above each other?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem this feature is available in Gephi yet; it has been requested in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/787) from the Gephi project.

The issue is still open and [was added to the milestones for the version 1.0.0 of Gephi](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/787#issuecomment-1153674365) on Sept 2022, so hopefully is implemented soon!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).